# Wrong behavior of the char arrays after strncpy

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, c-strings, strncpy

I am not a C-dev and I can get something wrong (I am doing the changes in the old code):

There is a function called `strncpySafe` (it is just a wrapper on `strncpy` as I can see):

```
void    strncpySafe(char *strDest, const char *strSource, int count)
{
    strncpy(strDest, strSource, count-1);
    strDest[count-1] = '\0';
}
```

The step by itself, where is a copy from source A to source B with an offset:

```
void Foo(const char *message) {
char line[1024];
...
strncpySafe(line, &message[message_offset], count);
```

In the last step they are modifying a `line[]` that was copied (the `message[]` should stay the same):

```
line[N] = 0;
```

On the last step I can see from a VSCode debugger that `line[N]` is being changed and in the same time the `message[N]` also modifies.
I am using `Ubuntu /g++-8, -march=x86-64, -std=c++11`.
Is it something about the same pointers? Is it the wrong usage of the strncpy?
Thank you.

ps: the same code is being used inside a game client for windows and linux and I can say that on windows it is not being reproduced (windows was built on an older c-compiler, haven't checked with the same c++11 build yet).

**EDIT**: to make it clear, the modification of the `line` and a `message` happens in the same time when I pass a step with `line[N] = 0;`

Removed incorrect naming of the `message_offset_2`. It is a `count`.
Let me provide an example of the execution:

```
strncpySafe(line, &message[5], 10); // It copies 10 elements from 5th
line[5] = 0; // this leads that message[5] also gets 0 for it's element
```

There are no errors with the boundaries (offsets and counters seems alright).

I agree that this code is deprecated and the logic might be unclear (why is that done that way) and I could use `std::string`. For me it was interesting why does it happen.

Comment: [Tangent] If you are using C++, why not use `std::string` to manage your string objects.  It makes code like this uneeded.

Comment: @gorZ Provide a minimal complete program that demonstrates the problem

Comment: `strncpySafe` is copying `count-1` characters from source to destination.  `line[message_offset_2] = 0;` is adding a termination to destination, but not needed, if you update strncpy to copy till count or pass offset+1 (depending on how counter is being used)

Comment: Are you saying that the chars of `line` are modified, and the chars of `message` are modified also -- by the *same* `strncpySafe` call?  That sounds like you've passed in a bogus `message` buffer that has aliased something on the call stack (underrun).  Or perhaps the message_offset_2 is larger than 1024.  One could `assert` such things.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow unfortunately I can't provide a demo example. I've tried to do the same via online gdb compiler and it was not reproduced.

Comment: also, you should error out if `message_offset_2` is greater than size of line (i.e. `1024`). Depending on desired behavior, either can pass `min(size of destination, message_offset_2)` or simply `assert`

Comment: @IgorZ Are the strings overlapped?

Comment: @IgorZ  Why are you using the name message_offset_2? It is not an offset. It is the number of characters to be copied.

Comment: _"unfortunately I can't provide a demo example"_ Why not? If you put your code in an online compiler, and couldn't reproduce the problem, then how are we to do the same and get a different result? You have to actually show us something we can work with. At the very least, produce a minimal example that still crashes on your local system even if it doesn't crash online.

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account that the array message is also changed as you wrote in your question then it is evident that you are using the function incorrectly and as a result you have undefined behavior.

For example the third parameter that you named like `message_offset_2` specifies the number of characters that should be copied from a string to the the destination character array. So it should not be named like `message_offset_2`.

Another reason of undefined behavior can be using of overlapped arrays.

So either the third argument is specified incorrectly or there takes place overlapping of character arrays.

But in any case the function is declared and defined badly.

If it is a wrapper around the standard C function `strncpy` then it should be declared at least like

```
char * strncpySafe( char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n );
```

Or if it is declared as a C++ function then

```
char * strncpySafe( char * s1, const char * s2, size_t n );
```

If the function is designed to copy `n` characters then the body of the function should look like

```
if ( n )
{
    strncpy( s1, s2, n );
    s1[n] = '\0';
}

return s1;
```

So the destination array shall have at least `n + 1` elements.

And (the C Standard, 7.23.2.4 The strncpy function )

> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is
>   undefined.